# CopyFromRecordset incorrectly formats cells as Date?

Tags: excel, vba, date-formatting

I have an excel sheet that loads data from a database, then puts it in an Excel Table using the CopyFromRecordset VBA command.  My problem is, a number of cells (which should be integers) keep getting formatted as a date, no matter what I do.  I've changed the number format in Excel to Number, but whenever I reload data from the database, the format switches back to date.

The datatype in the database is Integer, and yet, when I load data from the DB, Excel still changes the cell format to Date.  Even if an end-user enters an integer into the cell after loading data, excel changes it to a date.  For example, if I enter 5 into the cells, excel changes it to 1/5/1900.

Why would Excel keep changing these cells to dates, even after the format dropdown is changed to something else?

Things I've tried:

- Changed the format from date to number, general, & text.  It reverts to Date on CopyFromRecordset
- deleting the column and making a new one formatted as Number.  It still reverts on CopyFromRecordset
- Cast the datatype to integer in the select statement

Any other ideas?

A portion of the VBA code that loads the data from the database:

```
SQLStr = "Select ......, [SO] FROM v_TRACKING"
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";Trusted_connection=yes;"
rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

dataRange = "a13:az" & (rs.RecordCount + 12)

With ActiveSheet.Range(dataRange)
    .ClearContents
    .CopyFromRecordset rs
End With
```

All other columns stay formatted correctly, but for some reason the SO column gets formatted as a date.  I've been banging my head against a wall about this for a few days now, so *any* ideas would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered this problem before; it can be solved by using Cells property of the Range:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range(dataRange)
    .ClearContents
    .Cells(1,1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End With
```

Comment: This worked!  This is great because it still allows me to clear the contents of the range.  I didn't realize that one cell worked as the range.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

One cell is sufficient for a Range to format the column in a numeric format.

```
DataRange = "a13"
With ActiveSheet.Range(DataRange)
    With ActiveSheet.Range(DataRange).CurrentRegion
        .ClearContents
        .CurrentRegion.Columns("SO").NumberFormatLocal = "0_ "
    End With
    .CopyFromRecordset rs
End With
```